# Getting img tags from database works on index.php page, but not on any other page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm puttin html tags stored in a MySQL database, since they need to be able to be edited or deleted.

Now this works on the homepage, with the tags for the homepage looking like:

```
<a href="http://www.becxenvanloon.nl" target="_blank"><img class="sponsor" src="images/sponsoren/becx.png"></a>
```

This just doesn't work for any other page, which I did create a seperate column for to actually get a correct relative path, for as far as I know.

The tag for other pages looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.becxenvanloon.nl" target="_blank"><img class="sponsor" src="../images/sponsoren/becx.png"></a>
```

When I look in the inspector, because the images load then unload, the browsers makes two requests for the images, the first one succeeding and the second one failing.

The way I get the links from the database:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$slidersql = "SELECT image_link FROM kvw_sponsoren";
$sliderresult = mysqli_query($conn, $slidersql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($sliderresult) > 0)
{
    $slider = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sliderresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $slider .=  "<li>" . $row["image_link"] . "</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `MYSQL_ASSOC` doesn't work with the `mysqli_` api.

Comment: Same result with MYSQLI_ASSOC

Comment: check for errors then, via php and the query

Comment: No errors, as I said it is able to load the images at first, but then does something like a second request and fails to load them in that request.

Comment: *"but then does something like a second request and fails to load them in that request"* - I don't understand what you mean by that; can you explain in more detail and as to the steps you took? Is there a redirection happening somewhere in (a) file(s), `.htaccess` rewrite rule? The question's unclear to me.

Comment: No, no redirect but when looking in for example the network tab of the firefox inspector, you can see 2 requests for each of the images, 1 succeeding and 1 failing.

Comment: something else is causing this, other than what you posted.

Answer (score -1):

It's always better to reference the image with its full path, You have to save the image location images/xyz.png and always call as request URI + the path in the database, by saving the relative path, you will have to save many relative paths for each children page.

Comment: I actually tried using the absolute path like: http://example.com/images/image.png but that gave me the same result, I should have said that at the start as well sorry!

Comment: did you try to put the full path of the link STATIC and check what will happen?

Comment: This could just be me, but I don't entirely understand what you mean.

Comment: What I mean to replace the code login of the database path and insert in src the url of the image by urself to make sure that the image path is the real issue

Comment: Alright so when I do this it actually works. So when I navigate trough my domain to one of the images it works, but it appears that whenever I set the image src in the database to have the domain name in it as well, it for some reason that I can't find, changes it to localhost

Comment: If you set a base url for the page, in the header, the browser knows in which domain to look and will not use localhost.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp